# Creating constructors for Exception sub-class

Tags: java, exception, constructor, super

I'm creating a guessing game with a main class and two exception classes derived from Exception: a BadGuessException class and a TooManyGuessesException class.

The BadGuessException class is supposed to have 2 constructors, one no-arg that passes a message to parent constructor using super(), and one that takes a parameter and passes that parameter to the parent constructor also using super().

The TooManyGuessesException is supposed to have 2 constructors, a no-arg that passes a message using super() and also one that takes an `int` parameter and passes a `String` to the parent constructor of the value of the parameter.

I feel like I am working blindly on this, and would like some input on whether or not I am properly writing these two classes.

```
public class BadGuessException extends Exception
{
  public BadGuessException()
  {
    super("Sorry, that was an invalid guess!");
  }
  public BadGuessException(String message)
  {
    super(message);
  }
}

public class TooManyGuessesException extends Exception
{
  public TooManyGuessesException()
  {
    super("Sorry, too many guesses!");
  }

  public TooManyGuessesException(int guess)
  {
    String n = Integer.toString(guess);
    super("Sorry, you guessed " + n + " times!");
  } 
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't maintain control flow via exceptions. They exist for unexpected or undesired problems, not for handling the logic of whether the user has guessed too many times or not.

Comment: In addition to what @VinceEmigh said, is a bad guess *really* an exceptional situation?